# Getting Timeout in Jenkins while reading from console

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to read from the console in Jenkins using groovy. The url I am using is /consoleText. It was working for last 4 months but suddenly from today I am getting the following error:

```
Error while serving BUILD_URL/consoleText
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 5000/5000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Also:   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:482)
        at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:144)
        at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:102)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:41)
        at hudson.console.PlainTextConsoleOutputStream.eol(PlainTextConsoleOutputStream.java:77)
        at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.eol(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:60)
        at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.forceEol(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:94)
        at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.close(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:79)
        at hudson.console.PlainTextConsoleOutputStream.close(PlainTextConsoleOutputStream.java:87)
        at hudson.model.Run.doConsoleText(Run.java:2240)
Also:   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:482)
        at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:144)
        at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.finish(DeflaterOutputStream.java:111)
        at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:117)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.FilterServletOutputStream.close(FilterServletOutputStream.java:46)
        at hudson.model.Run.doConsoleText(Run.java:2240)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:541)
    at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:144)
    at com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:41)
    at hudson.console.PlainTextConsoleOutputStream.eol(PlainTextConsoleOutputStream.java:77)
    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.eol(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:60)
    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.write(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:56)
    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.write(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.Run.doConsoleText(Run.java:2239)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:347)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:374)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:243)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using Jenkins version 2.138.2

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
I am using Xmx as 8g with Java 64 bit.
I searched some websites and it seems jetty has a idle timeout set. But I am not able to find the place where I can modify the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you need to increase `--httpKeepAliveTimeout` (add this as a command-line option when starting the Jenkins master).

See the [Winstone/Jetty](https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone) page on GitHub for a list of all options.

Comment: I have updated it to 50s now. I will let you know if its working.

Comment: I am trying to read the console but the code is only reading the first 10000 lines while running in Jenkins but reading all the lines when running outside jenkins.
The code I am using is: 
url.withReader { bufferedReader ->
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                              //do something
                }
}

Comment: This sounds like a different issue. Please create a new question and accept this answer if the original "5000ms timeout" thing has been solved. Termination after 10000 lines depending on the reader's location appears to be unrelated to the original question.